# I am getting a missing a template error - I know for a fact i'm not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

File Structure

[image: File Structure]

I have checked everything already multiple times. Have searched the web long and hard. I can't find anything on this. I don't know what could possible be the issue! Please help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. HAHA you all are going to think im crazy. It's a name error. My mailbox controller is pointing to am inbox view and my view was named index -_- lol

Comment: Yep, I opened the screenshots and saw you had `inbox` vs `index`. Glad you could solve your own issue.